# working with dates in cakephp when publishing start and end date

Tags: php, jquery, cakephp

I created a date select option in cakephp and its ok.

My problem is that I want to create a publish start and publish end, the problem is, I don't know how to create one.

For example:

```
echo $this->Form->input('Lesson.duration_start', array('dateFormat' => 'DMY', 'label' => ''));

echo $this->Form->input('Lesson.duration_end', array('dateFormat' => 'DMY', 'label' => ''));
```

It both outputs a select option but I can set the duration end to a later day, which should be on or after the current day.

For example:

Start date: 29-Jan-2013
End date: 28-Jan-2013

I should not be able to select a day below the start date.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

You can set the minimum year ([`minYear`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#FormHelper%3a%3ainput)) to restrict past dates from previous years using the form helper. You can only realistically control the minimum year in your form as you'll need a full range of months/dates for dates in future years.

You'll then need to do some validation on duration_start/duration_end in your Lesson model to ensure the dates are valid. To compare dates you'll need to write a custom validation rule. [Take a look at this](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/cake-php/C-TetJiPT3U) to help you get going.

Comment: Hi, I have a problem, the model Lesson is not validating my "duration_end" and "duration_start" :(

Comment: @comebal it might be worth you posting a new question relating to your validation issue so that people can see what rules you have and how you are calling the validation. It should be a separate question to this one if you want further help. Without you providing details of your rules it is near on impossible to assist you.